# Question about example in Grimmett

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is example $4.8.4$ in Grimmett and Stirzaker's Probability and Random Processes.

Let $f_{xy}(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ be a joint density function with $0\leq y \leq x \leq 1$.
They then show the pdf of $Z=X+Y$ is $f_{X+Y}(z)=\log(2)$, if $z\in[0,1]$ and $f_{X+Y}(z)=\log(2/z)$ if $z\in[1,2]$. The support of $f_{X+Y}$ is $A = \{x\mid 0\leq z-x\leq x\leq 1 \}=\left[\frac{z}{2},\min(z,1)\right]$

I'm really puzzled about how they obtained the pdf of $X+Y$, and how the support of $X+Y$ gives a piecewise function.

I have determined that if $U=Y$, $V=X+Y$, then the region $0\leq y \leq x \leq 1$ is mapped to two duplicate (?) regions translated in the $U,V$ plane.

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The support of $f_{X+Y}$ is not $A$ but $[0,2]$.  What the book says is that $f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_A  \frac1x\, dx$  since for given $x$ you cannot have $x>1$  or $x<y$ i.e. $x < z-x$

Comment: OK. So how does that get the $X+Y$ pdf in two pieces?

Answer (score 1):

The support of $f_{X+Y}$ is not $A$ but $[0,2]$.

What the book says is that $f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_A \frac1x\,dx$ since for given $x$ you cannot have $x <0$ or $x>1$ or $x<y$ (i.e. $x<z−x$ and $x <\frac12z$) or $x>z$.

Sometimes that final constraint bites, namely when $0<z\le 1$. But there are two types of $A$ depending on $z$

- When $0<z\le 1$ we have $A=[z/2,z]$ and so $$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{z/2}^z \frac1x\,dx =\log(z)-\log(z/2)=\log(2)$$
- When $1<z\le 2$ we have $A=[z/2,1]$ and so $$f_{X+Y}(z)=\int_{z/2}^1 \frac1x\,dx =0-\log(z/2)=\log(2/z)=\log(2)-\log(z)$$

This is the reason it seems the density $f_{X+Y}$ appears to have two parts (it actually has four, being $0$ when $z<0$ or $z>2$)